# is it possible to merge two models in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to merge two models with two diffrent datasets, model1 is for face recognition and model2 is for clothes detection and the resulting model has to be able to identify individuals using their faces or gives an estimation about their identity from their clothes in case their faces are not showing up on camera,so i want to know if this is achievable or not, and if yes how exactly ?.

Comment: As far as I understand the math of neurons, it's not possible.

Comment: Even if you merge these models, what purpose would they serve?

Comment: Whether it is possible or not depends on entirely what you mean by "merging" them. This term does not have a specific meaning in this context, so you will need to explain further. In any case, this question will require more effort on your side; "tell me how to do X" is not a valid question for this site

Comment: Yes, you would need to specify what merging models means in this case.

Comment: I edited my question @Dr.Snoopy.

Comment: @xdurch0 I hope it's clear now

Comment: Why not use an ensemble based Random Forest Classifier? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html

Comment: @ASH i'm using cnn

Comment: Now I see the language about 'facial recognition'. Sorry about that.